# How do you bind to Xml in SilverLight/Windows Phone?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I am trying to use Linq to Xml and Xaml data binding in a Windows Phone app with no luck, following [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165615.aspx).

I've got some Xaml that looks like this:

```
    <Image 
           Source="{Binding Path=Element[image].Value, Converter={StaticResource UriBitmapConverter}}" 
           Grid.Column="2" MaxWidth="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The `DataContext` is an `XDocument` `<image>someuri</image>`. However this doesn't make it past the parsing stage as I get:

```
Additional information: Invalid attribute value
{Binding Path=Element[image].Value, Converter={StaticResource UriBitmapConverter}} for property
```

Is this sort of binding not possible in Silverlight or am I just missing something?

Comment: Have you tried using Element("image").Value?

Comment: yup. no joy   : error : Quote characters are only allowed at the start of values.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own object that wraps your XML document with the required properties needed by your page and use that for databinding.

Binding isn't smart enough to work with collections in the way you were trying.

Comment: The binding above works in wpf (the linked article shows an example on MSDN)

Comment: @ckackman Your above link is to the help file installed on your local machine. What is the equivalent online?